Navigate from matrix to table and show the data based on select done from matrix
I have a matrix with column A and column B in rows, column C and column D in values. I have 2nd table contains data linked with column A.I am not able to figure out how can I show the data from table 2 filtered on column A. it should be page navigation or tooltip.
Tooltip solution or page navigation is what I am looking for
